# return validation errors from laravel controller to vue

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js

everybody, I need to return error validation for this validation code to vue

```
  Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
 ])->validate();
```

I have tried

```
 $validator =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
 ])->validate();

if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('error validation', $validator->errors());
    }
```

but did't work for me

Answer (score 0):

List errors

```
$validator->messages();
```

Comment: Now My Post Method not Working

Comment: i get 500 (Internal Server Error) in console

Comment: Work in 5.0 laravel If last version use `$validator->errors()->all();`